# PHP: how to get the input encoded in ANSI

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

When adding a get parameter such as ?key=é , PHP transforms that value immediately into UTF8.
My script is not UTF8 and I must get the data in ISO-8859-1 by doing $_GET['key']

strlen of that value should be 1. Not 2.

How can I get that data in non-UTF8 without using a dependency such as mb or iconv.

Comment: I do not want to convert string to HTML. And I want strlen($_GET['key']) to give me 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When adding a get parameter such as ?key=é , PHP transforms that value immediately into UTF8. My script is not UTF8 and I must get the data in ISO-8859-1 by doing $_GET['key']

This statement is incorrect. PHP is not responsible here — **the web browser** is sending data to the web server in the UTF-8 string encoding, and PHP is passing it on to your application in that same form.

Keep in mind that "ANSI" is not a string encoding. It's a term sometimes used by Windows systems to (incorrectly!) refer to the system's native string encoding, which is usually Windows-1252 (similar to ISO-8859-1) on English systems, but can vary depending on the locale.

> strlen of that value should be 1. Not 2.

To have `strlen()` return the length in characters, rather than in bytes, you would need to activate PHP's [multibyte function overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php), which is a feature of the `mbstring` extension, or convert the string to a single-byte string encoding using `iconv` (which will be a lossy process).

There is no way to perform this conversion without either mbstring, iconv, or something substantially similar.